# HANA Equivalent of syscomments

Tags: sql, hana

I'd like identify all views and procedures in a HANA DB that use a given table. In SQL Server, one can query `sysobjects` and `syscomments` like the following:

```
SELECT
   o.name
FROM sysobjects o
JOIN syscomments c
   ON o.id = c.id
WHERE c.comment LIKE '%tableName%'
```

Is there an equivalent in HANA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that didn't take long to find. An answer can be found on the [SCN](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3526533).

```
SELECT
   Procedure_Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE Definition LIKE '%tableName%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best approach would be to search them using the Public Synonyms of the system, since the current user may not have SELECT privilege on schema SYS.
All objects can be found using:

```
SELECT *
  FROM OBJECTS
```

For procedures, you can just

```
SELECT *
  FROM PROCEDURES
```

For more public synonyms available, check Catalog folder -> Public Synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to do like this:

```
SELECT * FROM OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE BASE_OBJECT_NAME='YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
```

[Reference](https://help.sap.com/hana_one/html/_o_b_j_e_c_t__d_e_p_e_n_d_e_n_c_i_e_s.html)